# Wix - Running a deferred action after InstallFinalize

Tags: wix

Reading the Wix help I see that "Deferred execution custom actions must come after InstallInitialize and come before InstallFinalize in the action sequence."

However I have to perform a database upgrade on a remote box which needs to be run with the user credentials so I have created an immediate action and set it to run after installFinalize. Subsequently, I need to run another custom action to start a windows service which reads values from the database, this requires elevated (system) permissions, so needs to be a deferred custom action. Which as the Wix help kindly explains to me that I cannot do.

Any help, tips or Wix tricks appreciated please

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchServerUpgrade" FileKey="Config.exe" ExeCommand="/upgradeServer" 
          Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>

<CustomAction Id="LaunchServerDatabaseUpgrade" FileKey="Config.exe" ExeCommand=" /databaseupgrade"
          Return="ignore" Execute="immediate"/>

<CustomAction Id="LaunchServerStartServices" FileKey="Config.exe" ExeCommand=" /startservices"
          Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="LaunchServerUpgrade" Before='InstallFinalize'>
        <![CDATA[(SERVERCONFIGUPGRADE) AND NOT REMOVE)]]>
    </Custom>
    <Custom Action="LaunchServerDatabaseUpgrade" After='InstallFinalize'>
        <![CDATA[(SERVERCONFIGUPGRADE) AND NOT REMOVE)]]>
    </Custom>
    <Custom Action="LaunchServerStartServices" After='InstallFiles'>
        <![CDATA[(SERVERCONFIGUPGRADE) AND NOT REMOVE)]]>
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: So the machine that you need to do things to is a different machine to the one the installer is running on?

Comment: Yes but only the database. The installer is running on the server so can update the files, start the services etc... but the local system account it is using to do this actions does not have permissions to configure the database on the remote box.